# Google Play console shows not required features as used feature in app bundle

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I developed an android TV app using flutter, uploaded the release bundle to play console closed testing track(Android TV only release), however in my android TV(android 9) the app shows as incompatible with the device. I checked the app manifestfile, I have declared unnecessary hardware `<uses-feature` to `false`, but in the play console app bundles shows that the app uses those features, I think this is the reason my TV shows as incompatible.

- The question is why doesn't play console respect
  `android:required="false"` ?

  or
- Am I making any mistake here ?

[image]

here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.sensor"
    android:required="false" />



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:banner="@mipmap/ic_banner"
    android:label="My App Name"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category  android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

**UPDATE**

I commented all the `<uses-feature android:required="false"` part in `AndroidManifest.xml` and uploaded again

Now showing only 3 required features