# Weird behavior of android app bundle in play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

In one of my app I developed for TV, I have declared in Manifest to not use the unnecessary features for android TV as per the TV guide document
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware#declare-hardware-requirements

after uploading to play console, appbundle explorer it shows all the features as required, it is ignoring the `android:required ="false"`

[image]

I contacted the google play console support, and they are not able to help on this

[image]

The question I posted is related to the one previously asked.

1. [stackoverflow.com/questions/77513449/how-to-remove-faketouch-from-android-feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77513449/how-to-remove-faketouch-from-android-feature)
2. [Google Play console shows not required features as used feature in app bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77511583/google-play-console-shows-not-required-features-as-used-feature-in-app-bundle).

As a result, my app release has been on hold for an extended period. Any assistance would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic